# How do I create a HashMap with value of function?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to set HashMap of functions in a struct to a field in the struct and call them like below code. But it has compiler error. How can I fix?

main.rs

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct A{
  pub funcs: HashMap<&'static str, fn()->()>,
  f1:i32,
  f2:i32
}
impl A {
  fn func1(&mut self) {self.f1+=1;println!("func1 has called {} time(s)",self.f1);}
  fn func2(&mut self) {self.f2+=1;println!("func2 has called {} time(s)",self.f2);}
  fn set_funcs(&mut self) {
    self.funcs = HashMap::from([("f1",Self::func1),("f2",Self::func2)]);
  }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A{funcs:HashMap::new(),f1:0,f2:0};
    a.set_funcs();
    a.funcs.get("f1").unwrap()();
}
```

compiler error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:58
   |
12 |     self.funcs = HashMap::from([("f1",Self::func1),("f2",Self::func2)]);
   |                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn item, found a different fn item
   |
   = note: expected fn item `for<'r> fn(&'r mut A) {A::func1}`
              found fn item `for<'r> fn(&'r mut A) {A::func2}`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:18
   |
12 |     self.funcs = HashMap::from([("f1",Self::func1),("f2",Self::func2)]);
   |     ----------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found fn item
   |     |
   |     expected due to the type of this binding
   |
   = note: expected struct `HashMap<&'static str, fn()>`
              found struct `HashMap<&str, for<'r> fn(&'r mut A) {A::func1}>`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functions have an argument: `&mut self`. `self` has type `Self`/`A`. `A::func1` is `fn(&mut A) -> ()` not `fn() -> ()`

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct A{
  pub funcs: HashMap<&'static str, fn(&mut Self)->()>,
  f1:i32,
  f2:i32
}
impl A {
  fn func1(&mut self) {self.f1+=1;println!("func1 has called {} time(s)",self.f1);}
  fn func2(&mut self) {self.f2+=1;println!("func2 has called {} time(s)",self.f2);}
  fn set_funcs(&mut self) {
    self.funcs.insert("f1", Self::func1);
    self.funcs.insert("f2", Self::func2);
  }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A{funcs:HashMap::new(),f1:0,f2:0};
    a.set_funcs();
    a.funcs.get("f1").unwrap()(&mut a);
}
```

Comment: This is true, but only half of the problem. Try to make this work with the original `HashMap::from()`...

Comment: I don't now why you would think it is half of the problem, the author accepted it as solution. Anyways you can do that simply by using `HashMap::from([("f1",Self::func1 as fn(&mut Self)),("f2",Self::func2)]);`